# Replacing extension in the Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

I have a **pandas** dataframe containing song url with '.mp3' file extension. I want to replace '.wav'

The dataframe looks like this
[image]

[image]

Here you can see that, *Path* column contains the path of the song in the *Songs* directory. The song has '.mp3' extension. But I want to replace it with '.wav' extension.

How should I do it?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? The question is tagged `str-replace`; have you tried running `.str.replace()` on the `Path` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try this one :

```py
df['Path'] = df['Path'].str.replace('.mp3', '.wav', regex=False)
```

And if we want to be sure that we want to change the `.mp3` at the end of the string :

```py
df['Path'] = df['Path'].str.replace('.mp3$', '.wav', regex=True)
```